# SQL - trying to shift data in a table by one spot

Tags: mysql, sql

While manually entering data into an SQL database, I accidentally started entering in an incorrect row. In this particular table I have an ID column that increments 1,2,3... so I feel like this could be an easyish fix.

My table is named Sources. The column with the funky data is SenderID, and my incrementing ID column is just called ID

How would I shift data located in SenderID where ID = Z to SenderID where ID = Z+1, where ID is in a range (say > 33)? (SenderID where ID = 33 would be put into SenderID where ID = 34 and so on and so forth). When entering SenderID's, I got off by one row and need to move SenderID's in rows 34-99 to rows 35-100.

I'm thinking something along these lines but I can't quite get it because I'm not too familiar with SQL syntax:

```
Update SenderID
Set SenderID = (SenderID)+1   // The statement giving me problems
Where ID > 33;
```

The data I am trying to shift are text strings.

Comment: what is the table?  Is `Column` your table or is `Table` your table?

Comment: Are you after `Update Table Set Y = Y + 1 Where ID > 33`?

Comment: It's a little unclear. Can you provide a small but representative example.

Comment: You started entering data in an incorrect row, not an incorrect column.  ...my answer isn't relevant in this case.

Comment: I edited my question to the actual columns and tables because using variables was unclear.

Comment: YOu need to use `UPDATE SOURCES...`.  In other words, `UPDATE <TABLENAME>  SET <ColumnName>...` Otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: It doesn't work. It increases the value of all the SenderIDs... it does not move their row. Before, where ID=35 SenderID=8, ID=36 SenderID=4. After, ID=35 SenderID=9, ID=36 SenderID=5. I want where ID=35 for SenderID to take the value of SenderID where ID=34, and for ID=36, SenderID should become 8, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update sources s1 inner join sources s2 on s1.SenderID = s2.SenderID +1
Set s2.SenderID = s1.SenderID   
Where s1.ID > 33
order by s1.ID;
```

You had the wrong table name, its now correct

Updated query from comments, You would need a self join and update the tables which match.

You need to join the table to itself, so you have both what it should be and what it is together in the same row, the join condition (id = id +1) allows this to happen

The order by is to make sure its run in the correct order and for example 37 isnt processed before 36 which would set the ids wrong

Comment: It doesn't work. It increases the value of all the SenderIDs... it does not move their row. Before, where ID=35 SenderID=8, ID=36 SenderID=4. After, ID=35 SenderID=9, ID=36 SenderID=5. I want where ID=35 for SenderID to take the value of SenderID where ID=34, and for ID=36, SenderID should become 8, not 5.

Comment: Updated, Check the new answer

Comment: Are s1 and s2 supposed to represent something? When I copy/paste that code directly, I get a syntax error.

Comment: a self join needs 2 tables, s1 is a reference to the first sources table, s2 is a reference to the second

Comment: removed the aprts which would give bad syntax try again

Comment: i still don't understand. this problem occurred before i even created a 2nd table in the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58356/discussion-between-exussum-and-sakau2007).

Comment: Is this a primary key? DESCRIBE your_table might help. And 'does not move their row' is an interesting comment. MySQL doesn't drop rows in in any order - the db is optimized. The order is controlled by you when you run a SELECT and ORDER BY to control the output.

Comment: I know that rows are arbitrary in MySQL. However, I have an ID associated with each row. I incremented them 1,2,3... as I entered the data, so when I say row 8, I really just mean the entry where ID=7